# RegEx number [-99.99..-0.01]+[0.01..99.99]

Tags: regex, xsd

I want to validate a number. This number must be from -99.99 to +99.99 but except 0 (zero).
I came up with this RegEx expression

```
[-+]?((\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,1}[1-9])|(\d{0,1}[1-9]))
```

but it does not handle number of this type:

```
x0
xy.00
```

Any idea?

Edit:
  I am trying to do a restriction for xsd file.

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression to do this?

Comment: Why a regexp? Can't you just treat it just like a number?

Comment: Are the numbers always with two decimals, or is `45` also valid? Is only `0` invalid, or `0.0` and `0.00` as well?

Comment: @Bart - "45" is valid
"0", "0.0", "00.0", "00.00" are NOT valid

Comment: I am trying to set a restriction for <xs:simpleType> for XSD file.

Comment: Can there be only be 2 trailing decimal digits? 45.9342 is also a valid number and within the range too.

Comment: @Anurag: Maximum of to trailing decimal digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[+-]?([1-9]\d?(\.\d\d?)?|0\.[1-9]\d?||0\.0[1-9])
```

meaning:

```
[+-]?                 # optional '+' or '-'
(                     #
  [1-9]\d?(\.\d\d?)?  #   1 - 99.99
  |                   #   OR
  0\.[1-9]\d?         #   0.1 - 0.99
  |                   #   OR
  0\.0[1-9]           #   0.01 - 0.09
)                     #
```

Comment: What about numbers `0.10`, `0.11`, … `0.99`?

Comment: Indeed, forgot the `\d?` in the second OR-ed part (good catch!).

Comment: And what about `0.1`, `0.2`, …, `0.9`?

Comment: Now you have almost the same expression that I have. :-)

Comment: Err, they're covered by `0\.[1-9]\d?`

Comment: You forgot that in your compact expression.

Comment: Yes, they sure look a-like! <not-so-humble>What do they say about great minds?</not-so-humble> `;)`

Comment: But yours is a little more comprehensive as you didn’t combine the expressions for decimal places after `0.`.

Comment: Yes, especially with number ranges, I like to make it a bit more verbose in favor of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[-+]?([1-9]\d?(\.\d{1,2})?|0\.(\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d))$
```

This will allow any number starting with a digit greater than `0` followed by an additional optional digit (`[1-9]\d?(\.\d{1,2})?`). Or, if it starts with `0`, followed by a decimal point and followed by either a sequence that does not allow `00` nor `0` (`0\.(\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d)`).

Comment: @Gumbo: i made a little change, because numbers "x.y" was not allowed.
Replace "\.\d{2}" with "\.\d{1,2}". ---This works for me: [-+]?([1-9]\d?(\.\d{1,2})?|0\.(\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d))

Comment: @st.stoqnov: So only numbers with two decimal places are allowed?

Comment: @Gumbo: no, number with no, one or two decimal places are allowed.

Comment: @st.stoqnov: Then your comment “"x.y" was not allowed” is a little distracting.

Comment: I meant you example did not allows it.

Comment: @st.stoqnov: Ah, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply add two more cases for the missing numbers ... starting from your original regex,

```
 [-+]?((\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,1}[1-9])|(\d{0,1}[1-9])|(\d0)|([1-9]\d\.00)|(\d[1-9].00))
```

BTW rather than `\d{1,2}` it seems slightly better to write `\d\d?`; similarly `\d?` rather than `\d{0,1}`.

In any case this seems an exercise in pain.  Can't you use the regex to verify that this is a number in the format you want it, and use a separate constraint to make it not be zero?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```